How can I change/remove the shortcut fn+C for opening the Control Centre
Since I upgraded to macOS Monterey, fn + C (i.e. the fn key + the C key) opens the Control Centre in the Menu Bar.
How can I change or even remove this shortcut?
Same question for the shortcut fn + A.
Notes

In the Keyboard Preferences pane I have in the Keyboard tab the "Use F1,F2... as standard function keys" checkbox checked and want to keep it that way.

I know (thanks to @ user16145658) how to view the Control Centre shortcut: System Preferences =>  Accessibility => Keyboard => Navigation tab => Options => Commands tab. Then I see:



but despite the way the table looks the shortcuts cannot be changed here!!!!!!!!!!!!

In Sonoma that would be System Settings => Accessibility => Keyboard => Full Keyboard Access, the little round button with the 'i' which will do a pop up where you can scroll down to Control Center and see the default setting to Fn C. You'd see the one FnA nearby. I'd expect Monterey to vary at the lowest level pop up but likely recognizable. For Sonoma it's pretty well hidden by obscurity. Never loaded Monterey, got annoyed with the pace of incremental changes and waited for Ventura.

@user16145658 Thanks for chiming in. Where do I find this "Customise Keyboard Shortcuts" area? When I go to System Settings => Keyboard => Shortcuts I cannot find anywhere "Control Centre"...

Change Keyboard Navigation preferences for accessibility on Mac "To change these preferences, choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, click Accessibility , click Keyboard, then click Navigation."?

Thanks heaps @user16145658 for your hand holding. I found the table where the Control Centre shortcut is listed. Strangely though none of the shortcuts can be changed! (For a screenshot see the 2nd note I added to the question.)
